# C# Selenium bypass reCaptcha V2 I cant use callback function

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium, recaptcha

I using 2captcha.com api for bypass reCaptcha V2 but I cant use callback function.When I run callback function nothing is happening.This function output is "undefined".

I need run callback function.

[I want run this callback function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4KfN.png)

[When I run this function I get this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2aOh5.png)

Comment: Maybe your code is wrong

Comment: Hello, can you please provide some minimal and reproducible code to help us understand your problem and better assist you.

Comment: @HasanPatel I added a image to the question. I'm writing a bot for a website. The site does not belong to me. If there is no button in the 2captca api document, it wants me to run the callback function. But when I run it, nothing happens. API DOC https://2captcha.com/2captcha-api#callback

Comment: 2captcha.com isn't the most reliable. I recommend using deathbycaptcha, it's more reliable and has better documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Without the web link to the page where the captcha appears its going to difficult.
From what I can gather from  the Image you linked, try this from  Google chrome - Devtools - Console:

```html
var Callback_Str  = '___grecaptcha_cfg.clients[0].M.M'
var CResponse_jscript = 'JSON-code-received-from-provider'
document.getElementById('g-recaptcha-response').value = CResponse_jscript;
```

Once you run the code, click on the signin button.

Comment: When I run this code I get this error "Uncaught TypeError: Callback_Str.callback is not a function <anonymous> debugger eval code:4"  Web Link : https://visa.vfsglobal.com/tur/tr/pol/login

Comment: Sorry. The last line was not required. I have edited the code. Try it again and let me know

Comment: I run this code, nothing happened. When I run your code and click sign in button it's want to me complete the captcha

Comment: I noticed there is a callback in the sourcecode of the page. <script src="recaptcha.net/recaptcha/…" id="volt-recaptcha" async="" defer=""></script> You may need to call it referencing the element. Try: document.getElementById('volt-recaptcha').submit(); Alternatively you can send me a test login/password for the site, which I can play around with it and try getting it to work.